# How to access groupedValue in Solr Query Grouping

Tags: jquery, solr

I've got some issue to access groupValue in Solr query. I want to show groupValue in jquery autocomplete label. But I can't do it. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":29,
    "params":{
      "q":"strSO:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"strSO",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"2147483647",
      "wt":"json",
      "group.field":"strSO",
      "group":"true"}},
  "grouped":{
    "strSO":{
      "matches":112559,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"EV11777-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":53,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV11777-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV15872-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1829,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV15872-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV16143-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":929,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV16143-02"}]
          }},
```

### Here is my jquery codes

```
$(function() {
    var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?group=true&group.field=strSO&rows=2147483647&q=strSO:";
    var URL_SUFFIX = "&wt=json"; // facet.field=strSO&facet=on&rows=0";
    $("#searchBoxstrSO").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var URL = URL_PREFIX + $("#searchBoxstrSO").val() + URL_SUFFIX;
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                success: function(data) {
                    var docs = JSON.stringify(data.grouped.strSO.groups.groupValue);
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
                    response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value
                        }
                    }));
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            });
        },
        minLength: 0
    })
});
$(function() {
    var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?group=true&group.field=strSO&rows=2147483647&q=strSO:";
    var URL_MIDDLE = "OR strSO_ngram:";
    var URL_SUFFIX = "&wt=json"; // &facet.field=strSO&facet=on&rows=0"; // &facet.field=strSO&facet=on&rows=0 added
    $("#ngramBoxstrSO").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var searchString = "\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
            var URL = URL_PREFIX + searchString + URL_MIDDLE +
                searchString + URL_SUFFIX;
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                success: function(data) {
                    var docs = JSON.stringify(data.grouped.strSO.groups.groupValue);;
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
                    response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value
                        }
                    }));
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            });
        },
        minLength: 0
    })
});
```

Is there any idea to show it in html label? Or Can I access doclist's docs? It's last part of my project and if I do this correctly, I will be more happy man :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use stringify method as it converts a javascript object into a string. Just make sure that you get a JSON object from ajax response.

```
var docs = data.grouped.strSO.groups;

$.map(docs, function(value, key) {
    return { label: value.groupValue}
});
```

My test example:

```js
var data = {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":29,
    "params":{
      "q":"strSO:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"strSO",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"2147483647",
      "wt":"json",
      "group.field":"strSO",
      "group":"true"}},
  "grouped":{
    "strSO":{
      "matches":112559,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"EV11777-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":53,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV11777-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV15872-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1829,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV15872-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV16143-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":929,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV16143-02"}]
          }} ]}}};

    var docs = data.grouped.strSO.groups;
    
    var result = $.map(docs, function(value, key) {
        return { label: value.groupValue}
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this but autocomplete label shows nothing. :( Is it possible to access doclists's docs?

Comment: No, I tried both of them but autocomplete label shows nothing.

Comment: Okey, I made it. But I have another question. The autocomplete dropdown comes after writing 7 charecters at label. Is there any solution to make it 2 charecters. Thank you.